# Is there a CE mark requirement for positive control logic?

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, control-theory, regulations

I am looking into any requirements to obtain a CE mark that require control logic to be positive. In other words, if an electronic circuit has logic that either resets or turns the circuit off, is there a requirement that the control line activates the reset/shutdown by a low (ground) to high (such as TTL) transition or state change?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but I doubt that would be the case because all of the E-Stop circuits I have worked with signal shutdown on the transition from high to low; this ensures shutdown even if the E-Stop wiring gets disconnected.

Also, how would any operator ON-OFF switches work? Would they be "hot" the entire time the equipment was powered off, such that the high-low transition or low state signaled power-on, just so the high state or low-high transition could signal power-off?

Answer (score 1):

There is no legal requirement to follow any specified design method or standard. From 
https://www.gov.uk/guidance/ce-marking:

> It is up to you to ensure that your product complies with the
>   essential requirements of the relevant EU legislation. The use of
>   harmonised standards remains voluntary. You may decide to choose other
>   ways to fulfil these essential requirements. If you don’t follow the
>   safety requirements of a standard as it is written you will need to
>   show that your product is as safe, by presenting the relevant
>   documentation.